# Having trouble with some javascript regarding video players

Tags: javascript, html, api

I would like to know if there is a way with javascript to push a new link to the (data, and value) area?

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
   height="340px" 
   width="590px" 
   id="live_embed_player_flash" 
   data="http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf?day9tv" 
   bgcolor="#000000">
   <param  name="allowFullScreen" 
      value="true" />
   <param  name="allowScriptAccess" 
      value="always" />
   <param  name="allowNetworking" 
      value="all" />
   <param  name="movie" 
      value="http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf" />
   <param  name="flashvars" 
      value="http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf?day9tv" />
</object>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery:

```
var newUrl = '...'; //Assign your new URL here.
$('object').attr('data', newUrl);
$('object param[name="movie"]').attr('value', newUrl);
```

However, it looks like flash player does not take the attribute changes after it is embedded. Therefore whole embedding has to be renewed. Please see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6z5uR/). This fiddle re-embeds `<object>` tag with new URL.

Comment: Ok so I tried it in JSfiddle and it didn't work, I must be putting it in wrong. Can you take a look at it? http://jsfiddle.net/6yg83/1/

Comment: @SamK Your fiddle did not work in my browser. No video played in it. So I could not do anything with that fiddle. I tried in another fiddle. Changing the attributes on <object> tag did not work. Hence I changed the code to re-embed <object> tag with new URL. See http://jsfiddle.net/6z5uR/